# find result not append to text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below script find result not appending to the text.

file_vlist.txt file content file names as below

```
    filename1
    filename2
    ....
```

my script name is video.sh int having below code

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="file_vlist.txt"
while read -r line
do
name="$line"
echo "*******video******** - $name\n" >> output_video_new.txt
find . -type f -exec grep -l '$name' '{}' \; >>output_video_new.txt
echo "*******video******** - $name\n" >> output_video_new.txt
done < "$filename"
```

result is appending to text below incorrect format

```
*******video******** - file1\n
./video.sh
*******video******** - file1\n
*******video******** - file2\n
./video.sh
*******video******** - file2\n
*******video******** - file3\n
./video.sh
```

Comment: Remove the ' characters around $name.  These block the variable replacemnt by it's value, so what you are grepping for is `$name` itself, not it's value.

Comment: but when i execute the command in terminal/putty i can get the result for below . 
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'file1' '{}' \;

Comment: Actually, do the same for {}.

Comment: find . -type f -exec grep -l 'file' '{}' \;

Comment: And echo does an automatic carriage return, no need for the \n.

Comment: I understand, if you specify `'file'`, it will search for the text "file".  But if you put a variable between ' the variable is not evaluated.  It stays as text. so you are searching for `$name`, not the value of $name.

Comment: yes after removing from ' characters round $name it's working , thanks you again :)

Comment: no problem, please accept my answer :-)  (check mark on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="filelines"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    echo "*******video******** - $name"      >> output_video_new.txt
    find . -type f -exec grep -l $name {} \; >> output_video_new.txt
    echo "*******video******** - $name"      >> output_video_new.txt
done < "$filename"
```

- Removed the ' chars in the find command.  A variable inside ` chars is not evaluated.
- Removed the \n in the echo commands, echo add a carriage return automatically.